# Cloudformation Resource creation/deleteion timeout period

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

In [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/best-practices-custom-cf-lambda/) is written:

> **Set reasonable timeout periods, and report when they're about to be exceeded**
>
> If an operation doesn't execute within its defined timeout period, the
>   function raises an exception and no response is sent to
>   CloudFormation.
>
> To avoid this, ensure that the timeout value for your Lambda functions
>   is set high enough to handle variations in processing time and network
>   conditions. Consider also setting a timer in your function to respond
>   to CloudFormation with an error when a function is about to time out;
>   this can help prevent function timeouts from causing custom resource
>   timeouts and delays.

What is the exact solution behind this? Should I implement timeout on AWS Lambda
side or I can just set timeout period in CustomResource properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't set timeout on CustomResource.
What they are writing about in your citation is it's up to you to signal to Cloudformation just before your function times out.

You know about the remaining time by querying the context object which is the second parameter in your handler function. For example in [Python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context-object.html):

```
def handler(event, context):
    print("Time left:", context.get_remaining_time_in_millis())
```

You will see that the method call is similar in other languages, e.g [Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-context-object.html):

```
context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()
```

So, you could query the remaining time in a loop and when that value is getting low (e.g 3000ms), check if your resource is still not created and send an error signal to Cloudformation.

Second, do increase your timeout on your function as they recommended.